# restart windows GUI app after a system restart to let it work 7/24

Tags: windows, requirements, reliability

I have a program (with GUI) to run 7/24 in windows. When the pc restarts(for example after the electricity went off for a while), I want the computer to continue running the app, so I created a task scheduler basic task to run the app on startup.

1. When the task is set to be started on system start without caring for the user, the app GUI cannot be seen since the app starts in background. When I log in I cannot see it because it is started in the background and cannot take it to front.
2. If I select to start the app iff the specific user (btw there is only 1 user in the system) logs in, the requirement "run the app 7/24" cannot be achieved, because a manual user log in is required to start the program.
   So, how can we set a GUI program on windows to always work?

Comment: You cannot depend on a single system running non stop. Won't work. Provide for weekly update and downtime.

Comment: Maybe try calling a .bat/.ps1 in task scheduler that launches the app, or in task scheduler use something like `cmd /c start "" C:\Folder\Program.exe`

Comment: Also -- If you're using Windows 10, some apps can automatically restart after a reboot (Settings > Sign-in options > Restart apps), although I wouldn't depend on this feature if it was a production/mission critical program.  You could also try creating an entry in HKLM or HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`.  That should prevent issue #1.  I would look into a UPS if power outages are frequent and problematic.

Answer (score 0):

[Autologon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autologon) is a Microsoft tool to automate a user login at boot:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autologon

Obviously this is not very secure - read through the details on the linked page. However, it is one of the only ways to get software with a gui to automatically launch at startup in a valid, viewable session.

Most software generally has its back-end service processes detached from a front-end gui, like a webserver to a browser. I recommend searching for a similar solution where possible

Answer (score 0):

An application can be made to run as a Windows *Service*.

- A *Service* can be set to [automatically restart if it fails or is interrupted.](https://serverfault.com/questions/48600/how-can-i-automatically-restart-a-windows-service-if-it-crashes)
- A *Service* can be set to [run under specified credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-specify-the-security-context-for-services). If it's run as System, it would be available to all, but only accessible by Administrator. However, a service can be run with the credentials of a *user*.
- A Windows *Service* **cannot have a GUI** itself, but there is a **workaround**: [make the *Service* a controller to start the GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53232/how-can-i-run-a-windows-gui-application-on-as-a-service). See also [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/interactive-services) and [Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1159908/Yes-I-Know-But-I-Still-Want-a-GUI-for-my-Windows-S).

To [make a Windows application run as a service](https://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/), use a third-party tools, such as [SrvStart](https://github.com/rozanski/srvstart) (which you might need to build) or [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/download) to make each application a  Service. Set its [`Start` value](https://winreg-kb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sources/system-keys/Services-and-drivers.html) to 2 (automatic), or otherwise as needed.

***Caveats:***

- Using a Service requires that that it be started and stopped as a Service.
- The applications used to create a Service are considered "hack tools", since they make changes on a deep system level, not apparent to the user.
- Use care... it is possible to make a system unusable with mistakes in this process. **Make a disk image** so you can roll back if there is an issue!

Comment: Thank you. I'm using a windows server instance, it doesn't make sense that we have to use 3rd party tools to run a server-like process(service)